# appengine datastore - filter by string or integer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Will a query with a filter over IntegerProperty perform any better than a query with a filter over String Property? 
(same indexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically speaking, no. Any difference in the efficiency of comparing different datatypes is insignificant compared to disk access times.

Comment: Note however that if you decide to switch from StringProperty to IntegerProperty or vice versa you will have to convert all your entities and write them back -- if the indexed value is the integer 42, querying for the string '42' won't work, and vice versa.